# identify 2 column values exist per ID : SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Here's my example data

```
ID    desc           date
------------------------------
1     started       10-01-2020
1     restarted     10-01-2020
1     closed        10-01-2020
1     clear         10-01-2020
2     started       11-02-2020
2     closed        12-01-2020
2     cleared       12-01-2020
3     started       12-01-2020
3     restarted     12-01-2020
3     restarted     12-01-2020
3     clear         12-01-2020
```

Now my expected out put is to get the count of how many distinct Ids had both "started" and "restarted" in their desc column at least once.

Expected output:

```
month       distinctIDcount   count_started   count_restarted
Jan 2020          2                2                3
```

Here's what I have so far:

I am able to find those that have started and those that have restarted separately, but I need to find those only where both are present.

```
select 
    Format(date, 'MMMM-yyyy') as Month, 
    sum(count_started) as count_started, 
    sum(count_restarted) as count_restarted
from   
    (select 
         date,
         case when description = 'started' then 1 else 0 end as count_started,
         case when description = 'restarted' then 1 else 0 end as count_restarted,
     from 
         (select * 
          from #temp2 
          where date > '2020-01-01 00:00:00') a
    ) b
group by 
    Format(date, 'MMMM-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try first aggregating by `ID` and month, then aggregating a second time by month alone:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, FORMAT(date, 'MMMM-yyyy') AS Month,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN desc = 'started' THEN 1 END) AS count_started,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN desc = 'restarted' THEN 1 END) AS count_restarted,
               CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN desc = 'started' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
                         COUNT(CASE WHEN desc = 'restarted' THEN 1 END) > 0
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_both
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID, FORMAT(date, 'MMMM-yyyy')
)

SELECT
    Month,
    SUM(count_both) AS distinctIDcount,
    SUM(count_started) AS count_started,
    SUM(count_restarted) AS count_restarted
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Month;
```

Comment: No, distinctIDcount is actually only the count where both "started" and "restarted" are present in the same ID desc. What you provided will give me all distinct values.

Comment: @SPishere I fixed my answer (I think).

Comment: You did :) Its what I expected !! Thanks much :)